# Android Bitcoin Wallet, zero balance after keys import

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-wallet-app

I imported all my private keys (including those of change addresses) to Andreas Schildbach's Bitcoin Wallet  from bitcoin-qt and my balance is still zero. This disagrees with Blockchain, which clearly shows non-zero final balance. What is the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you did to import the keys? Do the corresponding addresses appear in the Android wallet's address book?

Comment: listaddressgroupings -> dumpprivkey for every address that has non-zero balance

Comment: Ok, that's how you exported them from bitcoin-qt, and sounds correct. How did you import them on the other side?

Comment: I looked up how .key files are constructed and just pasted respective private keys. It was imported successfully into Android wallet. 
 Maybe there is a more straightforward way? Tried pywallet -> multibit, but pywallet only outputs encrypted keys...

Comment: So to confirm, the imported addresses *do* show up in the "Your addresses" tab of the address book?  Have you tried the "Reset blockchain" option in the Settings menu?

Comment: Yes. I reset it a few times. Addresses that show up match output of listaddressgroupings.

Comment: Are you actually in sync with the block chain?  Under "Network Monitor" in the Blocks tab, do you have recent blocks (286904 is current right now)?

Comment: Affirmative. Last block received is 286907

Comment: Strange.  Then I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.  It may be time for a bug report to Schildbach and the Android Bitcoin Wallet maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you didn't set the wallets birthdate correctly. In any case usage like this is strictly discouraged.